# How to truncate string inside modern search template handlebars

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, search, spfx, modern-experience

I am using the SharePoint modern search results web part.

I am trying to truncate the Description variable so it only shows 50 characters.

```
{{Description.substring(0, 50)}}
{{Description.slice(0, 50)}}
```

I would have thought that would work as it's using JS right?

Can any body please point me in the right direction?

Is this where the helper goes?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom handlebar helper to truncate the string.

**Example**:

```
public registerHandlebarsCustomizations(namespace: typeof Handlebars) {
    namespace.registerHelper('trimString', function(passedString, startstring, endstring) {
        var theString = passedString.substring( startstring, endstring );
        return new namespace.SafeString(theString)
    });
}
```

Then, in template, you can use it like:

```
<p>{{{trimString value 0 50}}}</p>
```

**References**:

1. [Register Handlebars customizations](https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/extensibility/handlebars_customizations/)
2. [Handlebars - substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138518/handlebars-substring/25993386)