# Search result web part - formatting dates to days

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, search, spfx, modern-experience

I am using the SharePoint search Results web part which uses Handlebars JS.

I have two dates in these variables:

{getDate EventDateOWSDATE}

{getDate EndDateOWSDATE}}

I need to check if the 2 dates are on the same day, and if they aren't, I need to display to the browser 1day, 2day etc.

So if:

EventDateOWSDATE = 27/02/2021

EndDateOWSDATE = 29/02/2021

Print to the browser: 3 days

I could do this using JavaScript and moment, but not sure how to do this inside this web part using handlebars and I don't think I can add libraries like moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom handlebar helper like I mentioned in your [previous post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/290350/how-to-truncate-string-inside-modern-search-template-handlebars).

**Example**:

```
public registerHandlebarsCustomizations(namespace: typeof Handlebars) {
    namespace.registerHelper('compareDates', function(startDate, endDate) {
        //Your logic goes here
        //return expected result
    });
}
```

Below links will help you to get started with custom logic:

1. [Using handlebars helpers to detect if two dates match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57638707/using-handlebars-helpers-to-detect-if-two-dates-match)
2. [Handlebars Expressions](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html)

Comment: <3 Thank you Ganesh!