# Handlebars: How to hide text if variable is blank

Tags: search-results, display-template, managed-property, pnp-search-webparts

I've created a custom Sharepoint Search Result page using a list template, and I've added a line at the bottom of each result that shows
**Category:** *URL*

The URL is obtained from a custom column that is a managed property, which I've added into my Slots layout. Not every result will have a URL listed in the custom column. In those instances it shows **Category:** and then a blank space. What I would like to do is completely hide the category line, if the result has no value in the column.

I tried using the following:

```
{{#if @root.slots.CategoryURL}}
<div><b>Category: </b><a href="{{slot item @root.slots.CategoryURL}}"><i>{{slot item @root.slots.Summary}}</i></a></div>
{{/if}}
```

but all results still show the category line.

I also tried:

```
{{#if @root.slots.CategoryURL !=""}}
<div><b>Category: </b><a href="{{slot item @root.slots.CategoryURL}}"><i>{{slot item @root.slots.Summary}}</i></a></div>
{{/if}}
```

but this causes the web part to not display any results anymore.

How can I hide this line based on whether the column has data for that particular returned search result item?

Comment: Can you try using: `{{#if slot item @root.slots.CategoryURL}}
 <div><b>Category: </b><a href="{{slot item @root.slots.CategoryURL}}"><i>{{slot item @root.slots.Summary}}</i></a></div>
{{/if}}`

Comment: Let me know if this works for you. If not I can help you with custom handler.

Comment: This still causes the web part not to display any results

Comment: Can you try using custom handlebar(`isdefined`) like shown here: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#sub-expressions

Comment: I tried `{{#if (isdefined slot item @root.slots.CategoryURL)}}
                                    <div><b>Category: </b><a href="{{slot item @root.slots.CategoryURL}}"><i>{{slot item @root.slots.Summary}}</i></a></div>
                                    {{/if}}` 
but this also gave no results

Comment: You have to define custom handler in your code before using it in `#if`. Check this answer to know how to define custom handler: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/290350/how-to-truncate-string-inside-modern-search-template-handlebars/290351#290351

Comment: Sorry, where am I supposed to define it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144484/discussion-between-ronnie-and-ganesh-sanap).